# Identify a spider

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

This spider was making a web on the back porch.
Just wondering what kind of spider it is?

[image]

Comment: Please tell us about your location and if possible, the weather conditions when the picture was taken.

Comment: Did you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a [Barn Spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barn_spider) (*Araneus cavaticus*).

[image]

(photo from [here](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/143959-Araneus-cavaticus))